# Specifying output filename in DownThemAll

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using DownThemAll in Chrome to download a long series of CSV data files from our ServiceNow instance.  I have placed the URLs in a .txt file and imported that into the DownThemAll manager, and the downloads work.  However, it would be very convenient to be able to specify the output filename for each of the links.  Is it possible to add that to the CSV file?  I've tried what seem like reasonable ways, like comma (i.e. url,filename) and semicolon separating without luck.  Maybe that's just not a feature.  Is this possible?  Since I'm not the only one that does this process, I'm hoping to be able to just give the file to someone else and have all the names work properly.  Thank you.

P.S.  I believe that a generic Chrome tag is correct for this question, but please let me know if I'm wrong.  I'm happy to change it.